# How can I get my stand alone ActiveRecord::Base tool to connect to my production database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

This is a script I created to add users onto my production database.

```
puts "Name of the user"
name = gets.chomp

puts "Login of the user"
login = gets.chomp
```

etc. etc.....

What I want to do is connect to my production database so that I can easily manage new users without having to type a lot of fields multiple times.

At the top of the file I've tried a few ways to connect to the database but to no avail....

Attempt 1:

```
require 'config/environment.rb'
```

This connects me to the development database

Attempt 2:

```
require 'active_record'
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:production)

`establish_connection': production database is not configured (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

Attempt 3:

```
require 'active_record'
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => 'postgresql', :host => 'company_host')

load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)
```

Attempt 4:

```
  require 'active_record'
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => 'postgresql', :host => 'company_host', :database => '/var/local/config/database.yml')

  load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)
```

Attempt 5:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => 'postgresql', :host => 'host.company.com',
                                    :database => 'production', :user => 'user', :password => 'password')
```

My database.yml file entry for the production database looks like this.

```
production:
  db_host: host.company.com
  db_name: production
  db_pass: password
  db_user: user
```

I've tried other combinations found here [API guide](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class) but to no avail. I am running rails 2.3.8. and ruby 2.0. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does your `database.yml` file look like? Your first attempt assumes valid entries for the `production` database. Your subsequent attempts don't properly name a database. `Postgresql` requires a database name (not a file path name, which is used in SQLite). You passed the YAML config file in Attempt 4, which is incorrect. You also need to include username and password if there are credentials associated with the database. Attempt 4 is also missing the `=>` after `:database`.

Comment: Hey lurker, thanks for the reply, I've included my yaml file and have tried a few more attemps. The most recent being attempt 5 but this still isn't working. I keep getting the the error that there is uninitialized constant Rails (NameError). Do you have any other ideas or maybe some resources to share?

Comment: You say you *This is a script I created...* What kind of script? Is it a Rake task? A stand-alone Ruby script? If you want to operate on your database, you should make it a Rake task and include the Rails environment.

Comment: I made a file in the lib directory called account_creation.rb and it runs by simply executing ruby account_creation.rb or so it's supposed to. I'll give the rake task a try.

Comment: Hey lurker, the rake task was the answer to my problems. Once I created the task, all I needed to do was RAILS_ENV=production and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a special rake task.

1. Assuming I'd want a separate namespace `manual` and the name of the task is `create_user`:

   ```
   namespace manual
     task :create_user => :environment do
       puts "Name of the user"
       name = gets.chomp

       puts "Login of the user"
       login = gets.chomp
     end
   ```
2. Run `ENV=production rake manual:create_user`

You could even pass parameters to the rake task, if this helps.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but maybe this turns out a faster alternative for what you're trying to achieve.

Go ahead and comment on the answer if this doesn't help :)

Comment: Hey raviolicode, thanks for the reply, I don't think this is what I'm going for. I'm not trying to add data in a seeds.rb. Basically, my company has suspended account creation, so users temporarily have to email admins credentials for an account so I'm basically making the account for them.

Comment: I made a file called account_creation under the lib directory and then I simply call it with ruby account_creation.rb. Its supposed to work but maybe a rake task will work.

Comment: Yes, the seed task doesn't seem a good option for you. What about writing your own task specially for this? That way, you can use the Rails environment straight from there.